# SQLiteDataReader Appears to be Holding DB Connection Open

Tags: c#, sqlite, database-connection

**Synopsis**

I have a small local SQLite DB with a set records that are used to populate a ComboBoxList. The list is populated, and the DB connection released. No DB locking issues observed.

Then when a record is selected from the list, that record is retrieved and used to populate a LocalDBInstallRecord object. However, after populating the object, the DB connection seems to remain open and prevents any further access.

**The Code**

```
    public LocalDBInstallRecord GetRecord(string recordID)
    {
        LocalDBInstallRecord lir = new LocalDBInstallRecord();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM InstallationRecords WHERE RecordID = " + recordID;

        using (SQLiteConnection localDBConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionStr))
        {
            localDBConnection.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, localDBConnection))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        lir.RecordID = (uint)rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("RecordID"));
                        lir.DateCreated = rdr.GetDateTime(rdr.GetOrdinal("DateCreated"));
                        lir.Model = CheckDBNull(rdr, "Model");
                        lir.SCFirmwareVer = CheckDBNull(rdr, "SCFirmwareVer");
                        lir.DispFirmwareVer = CheckDBNull(rdr, "DispFirmwareVer");
                        lir.UCCFirmwareVer = CheckDBNull(rdr, "UCCFirmwareVer");
                        lir.Title = CheckDBNull(rdr, "Title");
                        lir.FOC = rdr.GetBoolean(rdr.GetOrdinal("FOC"));
                        lir.MCManufacturer = CheckDBNull(rdr, "MCManufacturer");
                        lir.MCType = CheckDBNull(rdr, "MCType");
                        lir.RailConvertor = CheckDBNull(rdr, "RailConvertor");
                        lir.PlantID = CheckDBNull(rdr, "PlantID");
                        lir.PlantOwner = CheckDBNull(rdr, "PlantOwner");
                        lir.PlantOwnerID = CheckDBNull(rdr, "PlantOwnerID");
                        lir.BoomLength = rdr.GetFloat(rdr.GetOrdinal("BoomLength"));
                        lir.ArticLength = rdr.GetFloat(rdr.GetOrdinal("ArticLength"));
                        lir.DipperLength = rdr.GetFloat(rdr.GetOrdinal("DipperLength"));
                        lir.MachineRecord = ReadDBBlob(rdr, "MachineRecord");
                        lir.DutyRecord = ReadDBBlob(rdr, "DutyRecord");
                        lir.CalibRecord = ReadDBBlob(rdr, "CalibRecord");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return lir;
    }
```

**Called Functions...**

CheckDBNull

```
    private static string CheckDBNull(SQLiteDataReader rdr, string col)
    {
        string str = null;

        if (!rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal(col)))
            str = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal(col));

        return str;
    }
```

ReadDBBlob

```
    private static byte[] ReadDBBlob(SQLiteDataReader rdr, string col)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        if (!rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal(col)))
        {
            SQLiteBlob blob = rdr.GetBlob(rdr.GetOrdinal(col), true);
            data = new byte[blob.GetCount()];
            blob.Read(data, blob.GetCount(), 0);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

**My Thoughts**

I'm sure there's easier ways to load the object, but that's not the issue...

I think the DB connection is being held open because the SQLiteDataReader can't be disposed of cleanly. I suspect that something in this function (in the LocalDBInstallRecord object) has got hold of an object by reference. I just can't see what.

I've tried not accessing the DateTime object in the record, but that's not it.

Should I be using a different method to access the DB in this case?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated, I think it needs a fresh set of eyes. Thanks.

**Further Research...**
I've found that if I try and us the SQLite DB with another tool, whilst the GetRecord() function has hold of the reader, I'm able to read the DB, but can't write. I get a database locked (RELEASE 'RESTOREPOINT';) error message from "DB Browser SQLite" application. But I think that's just because it's waiting for the reader to release.

Comment: Not sure about SQLite, but some DB drivers deliberately keep the actual DB connection open, in a connection pool, to improve query times.   if LocalDBInstallRecord  is purely properties, then it shouldn't 'keep anything open'.    FYI `SELECT *` is not good SQL, as the query may return columns your code is not reading (so wasting bandwidth), also, your code only returns 1 record, but your code will potentially query multiple records, and populate the same instance with those records.  use TOP(1) to guarentee one record is returned, and then the `while(rdr.Read())` can become a check.

Comment: @Neil I'm new to C#, so when you say purely properties, I'll need help to clarify if this is the case. The class has properties, functions(?), and a constructor...

Comment: If LocalDBInstallRecord purely contains `public int RecordID {get;set;}` etc, and has no code, then it's a 'record'.

Comment: @Neil No the class LocalDBInstallRecord contains functions to read the Datablobs.

Comment: `Read the datablobs`, you mean populate data from the database, or further process that data that has already been populated?   Also, I've just spotted a classic SQL injection case, you should fix that immediately.  Your SELECT statement blindly adds whatever was passed into it, that string could contain some SQL that will DELETE YOUR DATA !   You should parameterise your query.

Comment: Thanks, yes the SQL Injection attack is on my mind, but this is still a first build and nowhere near release. When I say "Read the datablobs," the blobs are binary files generated by PLCs, which I read using a bespoke data format reader that generates either strings, ints, or floats. The LocalDBInstallRecord reads the headers contained in these blobs.

Comment: But my understanding is that "ReadDBBlob()" creates a byte[] and makes of copy of the blob, which should allow the blobs in the datareader to be disposed of?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239451/discussion-between-neil-and-variablesquid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came in the function ReadDBBlob. The SQLiteBlob is IDisposable, and it's use wasn't encapsulated in a using clause. As a result the SQLiteBlob wasn't being diposed of, and this held the reader and hence kept the connection open...

**New ReadDBBlob**

```
    private static byte[] ReadDBBlob(SQLiteDataReader rdr, string col)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        if (!rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal(col)))
        {
            using (SQLiteBlob blob = rdr.GetBlob(rdr.GetOrdinal(col), true))
            {
                data = new byte[blob.GetCount()];
                blob.Read(data, blob.GetCount(), 0);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I hope this saves someone some time.